# ER Diagram keeps showing One-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I just generated a ER Diagram from MySQL workbench using table I'd created before and I encounter some problems.

[image: diagram]

My problem is, the ER Diagram shows only one-to-many relationships. One of those relationship is between `bokar` table and `bokar_detail` table using field `nomorbokar` on each table, which I've marked before (take a look at red spheres).

In fact, the relationship between those two tables is supposed to be one-to-one relationship, because each table can only contain one `nomorbokar` record, no duplication.

I got that rule by setting `nomorbokar` field in `bokar_detail` table as a foreign key, referencing on `nomorbokar` field in `bokar` table.

I set the referenced field as unique key (to prevent duplication) and then set the foreign key as primary key (to prevent duplication) which will obviously generate one-to-one relationship.

What's wrong with my ER diagram?

Comment: can you embed the image in the question

Comment: I'm sorry I can't. The system automatically prevented me from doing so. I only have one single post.

Comment: Can you give the full link to the image as the one you've supplied throws a 404 image not found.

Comment: The question has been edited, need help, please

Answer (score 0):

Remove relationship between Users & Boker_Detail as that is not required. Others are OK.